# private folder beside public_html on 000webhost

Tags: html, web, web-hosting

I host my website on 000Webhost.
I have to fill all my scripts for my website in the folder "public_html" (Example: /public_html/index.html).

I would like to have a "private" folder on the same level (Example: /private_html/variables.php) like public_html, but where only I can access and place things in it.

Is there any possibility for it or some other host which will support this function?

Comment: If you go down one level from public_html, it should be private, no? Yes, this would be available on other servers, it is probably available here as well though. You also could possibly modify the permissions so the apache user can't access the folder.

Comment: I tryed and had make a public and a private folder, but only the stuff from the public folder were shown and couldn't get the script from my private folder. 
Before I had test it in my offline apache serve on mi pc. And there it works.
I have to say that the folder public_html is given from 000webhost and there you have to file your website

Answer (score 0):

Private "stuff" is not meant to be on a **web server**. Create a small app server where you can a have a database and keep its IP private or get some security from the hosting service (better) and connect to it maybe from SSH (PuTTY) and then exchange files over it.

Anyway, a very basic workaround way to implement what you need is something like a PHP script that asks for admin credentials when a page under that folder with a URL(even if someone gets access to it when you would try to keep it private in the first place) is hit. From there, after you get authenticated, you can load the rest of the page using the same script which will basically present you a management tool or UI for yourself...Say if you'd want to upload some files or delete them.

Comment: You can have private stuff on a web server. How do you expect the web server to be able to interact with a database otherwise?

Comment: No, that's okay, you're right for basic websites. But in that way you expose your database to SQL injection and other vulnerabilities which can be easily eliminated when processed through a web application kept in more like a private subnet. Plus management of database becomes difficult and time-consuming.

Comment: How would that ever open a user to SQL injections? Here's my only DB interaction `select now()`, how is that injectable?

Comment: Okay :D you're presenting a very specific and minimalist use case. What if the website needs to diversify and scale in a very complex way, which is the very valid scenario? I used to keep the databases along with my web files in school but in enterprises, they follow this beautiful server architecture.

Comment: Private data just doesn't go in a web accessible directory.